# Buffered Reader: Reset won't reset

Tags: java, bufferedreader, reset

I'm currently learing about the mark() and reset() methods of the BufferedReader and want to do the following:

I parse a CSV, set up like this (spaces as delimiter):

```
555 value1
555 value2
600 foobar
700 whatever
```

Each line, one object (adress) is created with the first number as its ID. When the ID is used multiple times, I want to compare the values in the second column and proceed afterwards.

With the data above, my code does compare the two values with ID 555, but fails to create an object with the third line (ID 600).

***Mistake found***: splitted the first line after parsing the new one. Simple mix up of variables.

My setup is similar to this:

```
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    br.mark(1000); //save current line

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(line.split(delimiter)));
    Adress a = new Adress(Long.parseLong(list.get(0)); //create object

    while (((checkLine = br.readLine()) != null) && exit == false){

        List<String> nextLine = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(line.split(delimiter)));
        long nextId = Long.parseLong(nextLine.get(0)); 

        if( nextId == a.getId() ){
            System.out.println(nextId + " vs. " + a.getId());
            br.mark(1000); //mark the next line if it has the same ID

            //[...] do more stuff
        } else{
            exit = true;
        }

    }

    br.reset(); //reset to the last line with the ID
}
```

Sysout:

```
555 vs. 555
555 vs. 555
555 vs. 555
```

Comment: You can make br object null also after use :p

Comment: Does Adress.getId() return long or Long? And when does exit ever get reset to false?

Comment: Hey Barry,
I found the mistake. It was related to my stupidness and not to Java. :o|
How can I mark this solved? Bloom helped a lot, but his answer wasn'T the actual solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a couple of issues in the code:

- Inside the second while() loop you are still splitting the string "line", but the while loop assigns the input to "checkLine".
- You don't reset "exit" to false - this should probably happen after the br.reset().

Comment: Hey Barry, thanks! I found the first issue, but you're also right about the second one. I'll change that in my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if your addresses are separated by spaces , and the different elements of your address are also separated by spaces , then this line does not give you addresses , it gives you elements .

```
List < String > list = new ArrayList < String > ( Arrays . asList ( line . split ( delimiter ) ) ) ;
```

Comment: Hey Bloom, thanks for your reply. When changing `mark(1000)` to `mark(0)`, I get an `IOException: Mark invalid` (thrown on the `br.reset()` line).

Comment: are they different though ? ie . address1part1 , address1part2 ;

Comment: Hey, I edit my question and added some code. I also edit my test data and the mistake seems to be that `nextID` isn't set to the latest value. It is still 555 when br has parsed line 3.

Comment: Found the mistake:`it was indeed the list splitting. I splitted the wrong line...^^ Thanks for your help though, Bloom. How can I give you reputation or anything in return? I'm kinda new to this forum, too. :)

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was the following variable-mixup (solely my stupidity was the mistake!):

```
while (((checkLine = br.readLine()) != null) && exit == false){
    List<String> nextLine = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(line.split(delimiter)));
    [...]
```

The List nextLine has to be changed from line.split to checkline.split:

```
List<String> nextLine = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(checkLine.split(delimiter)));
```

**Thanks to everybody helping!**